# Gradle: dependencies inside build.gradle vs. inside buildScript()

Tags: gradle, dependencies, android-studio

Inside my module build script (build.gradle) I can set dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '3.6.7.Final'
}
```

[Gradle Example 8.2](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html)

I can also use `buildscript()` method inside the build script and set dependencies:

> If your build script needs to use external libraries, you can add them
>   to the script's classpath in the build script itself. You do this
>   using the buildscript() method, passing in a closure which declares
>   the build script classpath.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.2'
    }
}
```

[Gradle Example 59.6](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/organizing_build_logic.html)

My question, are these the same? Is there any difference between these two ways of setting dependencies for the build script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a big difference. The former declares (compile) dependencies of your code; the latter declares dependencies of the build script itself (i.e. it allows to use commons-codec right in the build script).